# Error: 'Flutter/Flutter.h' file not found

Tags: flutter, crashlytics

I added firebase_crashlytics to my Flutter project and followed the Firebase guideline in order to install it.

On *flutter run* the app works well without any error.
ONLY DURING *flutter build ipa* I get this:

```
    Error (Xcode): 'Flutter/Flutter.h' file not found
/project/ios/Runner/GeneratedPluginRegistrant.h:9:8


Error (Xcode): failed to emit precompiled header
'/Users/macnew/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-biyumwxiyqxyjkacscuqcbwbjroj/Build/Intermediates.no
index/ArchiveIntermediates/Runner/PrecompiledHeaders/Runner-Bridging-Header-swift_26UGEQJVHLD5H-clang_19ZWN9O
PIOOJI.pch' for bridging header '/project/ios/Runner/Runner-Bridging-Header.h'


Encountered error while archiving for device.
```

Any advice about this?

I'm using firebase_crashlytics 2.8.6 (latest version) and flutter 2.10.5 (without null-safety).

Answer (score 0):

Since I tried every solution given on StackOverflow and Github (Flutter repo), here you have the solution:

- Delete the "ios" folder
- Run the app and create the iOS project
- Inside the "ios" folder ("cd ios"), run the command "pod install"
- Follow the [official guide](https://firebase.google.com/docs/crashlytics/get-deobfuscated-reports?platform=ios&authuser=0) by the iOS side

This is the only solution that works.